# What's wrong with this MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a query that I'm trying to run at the moment, which isn't working properly.

```
    require_once("functions.php");
$db_hostname = 'localhost'; 
$db_database = '***'; 
$db_username = '***'; 
$db_password = '***'; 
$db_status = 'not initialised'; 
$str_result = ''; 
$str_options = ''; 
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password); 

//write connection errors to external file
$handle = fopen("errorcon.txt", "w+");
$string = mysqli_connect_error($db_server);
fwrite($handle, $string );
fclose($handle);

$db_status = "connected";
//open database connection
mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
$pname = $_GET['pname'];
$uname = $_GET['uname'];
$ssaw = $_GET['ssaw'];
$feel = $_GET['feel'];
$loc = $_GET['loc'];

$handle = fopen("SearchCheck.txt", "w+");
$string = $pname . $uname . $ssaw . $feel . $loc;
fwrite($handle, $string );
fclose($handle);

$query = "SELECT tblPhoto.PID, tblPhoto.Name, tblUser.Username, tblPhoto.URL, tblPhoto.Description, tblPhoto.Season, tblPhoto.Feeling, tblPhoto.Location 
FROM tblPhoto
LEFT JOIN tblUser ON tblPhoto.UID = tblUser.UID
WHERE tblPhoto.Name LIKE '%$pname%' AND tblUser.Username LIKE '$uname' AND tblPhoto.Season LIKE '$ssaw' AND tblPhoto.Feeling LIKE '%$feel%' AND tblPhoto.Location LIKE '%$loc%'"; 

$results_array = array();
$results = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results)) {
 // $results_array[] = $row;
//}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results)){
$table_data[]= array("PID"=>$row[0], "name"=>$row[1],"username"=>$row[2], "URL"=>$row[3], "desc"=>$row[4], "ssaw"=>$row[5], "feel"=>$row[6], "loc"=>$row[7]);
}
echo json_encode($table_data);

$handle = fopen("error2.txt", "w+");
$string = mysqli_error($db_server);
fwrite($handle, $string );
fclose($handle);


mysqli_close($db_server); 

?> 

$results_array = array();
$results = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
```

The variables are GET variables passed to the php in the URL and are working properly, in this specific test pname, uname, feel and loc were set to * while ssaw was set to winter.

When I ran a test run of the query through PHPMyAdmin with the variables manually set to the above values, I got the following (unhelpful) error message:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT tblPhoto.PID, tblPhoto.Name, tblUser.Username, tblPhoto.URL, tblPhoto.De' at line 1"

Anyone have any idea why the error message isn;t displaying properly? Or have eagle eyes and spot some error in the query?

For reference the test run I ran in PHPMyAdmin had been edited from the variables to

```
"SELECT tblPhoto.PID, tblPhoto.Name, tblUser.Username, tblPhoto.URL, tblPhoto.Description, tblPhoto.Season, tblPhoto.Feeling, tblPhoto.Location 
FROM tblPhoto
LEFT JOIN tblUser ON tblPhoto.UID = tblUser.UID
WHERE tblPhoto.Name LIKE '%*%' AND tblUser.Username LIKE '*' AND tblPhoto.Season LIKE 'winter' AND tblPhoto.Feeling LIKE '%*%' AND tblPhoto.Location LIKE '%*%'"
```

EDIT: Included entire php file at request from Mihai

Comment: `$results = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);` change into `$results = mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_server));` and post the error that it gives

Comment: `LIKE 'foo'` is pointless. Without wildcards, `like` is just `=`.

Comment: @Mramaa I can't do that exactly (This is a mobile app accessing the php remotely) but the php should be writing mysqli_error into a text file on the server if there is one; I checked and that file is blank so it's not throwing anything up from there.

Comment: Show your connection.Do you connect with mysqli,do you select a db?

Comment: EDIT misread that. My connection is correct though; It's copy and pasted from several other (working) php files accessing the same database. The error is in the query itself.

Comment: Make sure the db is the correct one

Comment: @Mihai Yup, checked that.

Comment: Just to make sure you know a db is different than a table?

Comment: Yes. I'm not a complete idiot. Like I said, the connection part of this code has worked several times before for different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Not working in PHP, but a consideration... I don't know if it is a possible bad wrapping issue on the opened string spanning multiple lines and the cr/lf is being somehow ignored and it is joining from one line to the next

```
$query = "SELECT tblPhoto.PID, tblPhoto.Name, tblUser.Username, tblPhoto.URL, tblPhoto.Description, tblPhoto.Season, tblPhoto.Feeling, tblPhoto.Location 
FROM tblPhoto
LEFT JOIN tblUser ON tblPhoto.UID = tblUser.UID
WHERE tblPhoto.Name LIKE '%$pname%' AND tblUser.Username LIKE '$uname' AND tblPhoto.Season LIKE '$ssaw' AND tblPhoto.Feeling LIKE '%$feel%' AND tblPhoto.Location LIKE '%$loc%'";
```

making it something like

```
...Feeling, tblPhoto.LocationFROM tblPhotoLEFT JOIN tblUser ON tblPhoto.UID = tblUser.UIDWHERE
```

Notice the "FROM", "LEFT JOIN" and "WHERE" are butt up next to the previous field reference not having any space?

Also, and just a side note.  You have a LEFT JOIN to the Users table, but include the Users table in the WHERE clause forcing this into an INNER JOIN, thus requiring a match in the users table.  Don't know if that was intentional or not, but if you were looking for a specific user that didn't have the other elements, you would get no rows... Again, it is a side-note, not specifically your syntax error in itself.

Comment: In general in these kind of messages,the error its just before the query starts  `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT  ` So the error for him its right at the beginning.Its really weird.